# where to find Ubercart translation files

Tags: drupal, text, location, translate

I am trying to update language specific text files ("po files") for Ubercart, but it is unclear who/where these files are maintained.  There are several places sited but I am not sure which is maintained?

http://ftp.drupal.org/files/translations/6.x/ubercart/

http://l10n.privnet.biz/translation_group/

Also a description of how to do this in Drupal.  In Drupal (link: admin/build/translate/import)  there are several text groups to select. Do I have to repeat update for each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need only to do it once.
i usually get translations from localize.drupal.org but you will need to register there.